# How do I add a possibility to pass filenames to my custom transformer in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

everyone! 
I am a novice in machine learning and sklearn (not a strong programmer either). 
I am currently making an email classifier and I wanted to add some additional features to the ones that are provided by CountVectorizer. So I built a custom transformer like this:

```
class ExtraFeaturesTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        features = []
        for x in X:
            features.append([....])

        return features
```

Then I combine the features

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='filename')

combined_features = FeatureUnion([("extra_features", ExtraFeaturesTransformer()), ("word_feactures", vectorizer)])
X = combined_features.fit_transform(filenames)
```

As a result my custom transformer treats filenames like X (obviously). How do I make it work like CountVectorizer which has parameter input='filename'?

I tried to look at CountVectorizer source code (didn't make much sense to me) and added VectorizerMixin to the list of classes from which my transformer inherits and self.input to init. But I am stuck and don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to define the `__init__` method and to pass to it any arguments that you plan to use in your `fit`/`transform` functions in addition to the usual `X` input. See [this part of CountVectorizer code for inspiration](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L687-L694)

P.S. It looks like a general python question rather than an sklearn question.
P.P.S. I'm not sure if you need to derive from `VectorizerMixin`, unless you plan any of the functions associated with that class